# HTML link to open an app but with parameter(s)

Tags: url, shortcut, shortcut-file, location-href, windows-shortcut

I want to make a HTML link that can open an app, I already know how to do that but without a parameter

HTML link:
`<a href="osu://">`
Windows shortcut Target that works like that link:
`"C:\Program Files\osu!\osu!.exe"`
Windows shortcut Target that works as I wanted to:
`"C:\Program Files\osu!\osu!.exe" -devserver example.com`

How do I make HTML link that works like a Windows shortcut with that parameter inside the Target

(sorry for bad English)

I tried using `<a href="osu://?devserver=example.com">`, and ofcourse it didn't work

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.